# TypeScript built-in dictionary type/indexer shorthand?

Tags: typescript

There're pre-made types for number-indexed indexers (`T[]` and `ArrayLike<T>`), but there doesn't seem to be one for string-index ones. This makes declaring them rather tedious. Is there a type declaration like below that I missed?

```
type Dict<V> = {[key: string]: V}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any by default. `ArrayLike<T>` and `T[]` work for numbers because arrays are indexed by numbers. For objects you have to define your own.

However you can use `Map<K,V>` to create a typed map.

```
let mapping = new Map<string, string>([["key", "val"]]);
```

Comment: That's annoying. They added loads of pre-defined ones like `Record` and `Partial` for `keyof`-indexed ones but still missing the most basic case....

Comment: There is `Map<K, V>` which might suit your needs. For object literals you have to define it yourself.